# How to find out if a conference submission deadline is likely to be extended?

Tags: conference, paper-submission, ieee, deadlines

I am writing a paper for a conference. I have finished the paper, but I must review some experimental results and this requires some additional days.

How can I find out the probability that the submission deadline will be extended?

Comment: Why don't you try contacting them?

Comment: Why not? I try. Thanks @Compass.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just look at past editions and see if there was indeed an extension. If they always do it, there will be another one; if they never extend, there is no reason to believe they will start this year.

If they don't, you could always give a shot to a polite email to the organizers and explain your situation. Perhaps you can submit a tentative proposal, with the uncertain data, and submit a refined version later (provided it doesn't change much).

Comment: More specifically, don't even bother writing them, just check past editions. If they always extend, they'll extend. If they never extend, they won't this time, either.

Comment: @xLeitix good point. I have now switched them around.

Comment: Yes, last year there was an extension from February 17 to March 6, and so three year ago. But is not clear if this practice repeats every year. Unfortunately, every year the site is different (is not like www.conference.com/year/), but you have answered my question. Thank you.